# How to assert varying payload of connector call in for-each loop in Mule 3 (Munit 1.11)?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

My Mule 3.9 app (Munit 1.11) consists of a for-each loop in which a http connector is called in each for-each iteration. The payload with which the connector is called varies in each loop. Now I would like to assert the payload in a corresponding Munit test for each for-each iteration. The idea is to use something comparable to the JavaScript Jest function toHaveBeenNthCalledWith so that a assert payload can be defined for each nth connector call. Is there some build in function for this available or is there a workaround for this?

Comment: HTML Connector? Do you mean an HTTP Connector?

Comment: yes of course, mistake is corrected, sorry for the typo and thanks for the hint